# Macro creates multiple page breaks instead of just one

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a macro that finds an instance of style H1 followed by style H2, and inserts a page break between them. And reiterates this till it gets to the end of the document.

However, the macro adds multiple page breaks (maybe 50 of them) instead of just one.

what did I do wrong and how to correct this?

The code:

```
Sub Force_page_break()
'
' Force_page_break Macro
'
'
    Dim Eloop As Integer
    Eloop = 1
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Do While Eloop = 1
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    If Selection.Find.Execute = False Then
    Eloop = 0
    Exit Do
    End If
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
    Loop
    ActiveDocument.Save
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a line

```
Eloop = Eloop + 1
```

after the line

```
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
```

to get out of the loop?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that, and now it indeed adds only one page break, but only in one chapter. The macro does not reiterate.